# Programmatically connecting to another Network operators

Tags: android

I am trying to do a little app to list and connect to other Network operator.

I list them by going to:

- Settings
- Wireless Controls
- Mobile networks
- Network operators
- Search networks

And I connect to other Network operator by clicking on one of the list.

I've been searching methods from [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) but I don't find something like `connectTo()` .

Any ideas of how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I learn that for the sake of security there aren't any public APIs to manage this so the only option is to send the user to the system PreferenceScreen within my app.

Comment: can we do this by java reflection or something ?? I really need this feature. Thanks for help