# connecting to an existing network programmantically

Tags: android, android-wifi

How can I connect to an existing network programmatically using WifiManager? I am trying to write a program that connects to a wifi network without having to see the inbuilt android list of available networks.

Thanx

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373727/programatically-connecting-to-another-network-operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply carry out any network operation, say an HTTP request execution, without bothering about the WifiManager, your operation will automatically execute on the network that is currently connected.

If you want to connect to one of the available networks without the user selecting which one, I don't think that is possible. Don't you think that is a blatant breach of the user's preferences & security?

HTH,

Akshay